# Integrate Google Sheets API on Adobe AEM

Tags: java, aem, google-sheets-api

I am trying to integrate Google Sheets API on Adobe AEM, I was reading the documentation but I have some questions related to the creation of the Credential object
Here is the code

```
    private Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

            if (jsonKeyObject == null || jsonKeyObject.isEmpty()) {
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("Could not create API Key Json Object");
            }

            // Load client secrets.
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new StringReader(getAuthorizationJsonString()));

            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    netHttpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory())
                    .setAccessType("offline").build();

            return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        }
```

My question is, can I use a different way to create the Credential object? I don't want to use the LocalServerReceiver and I don't want the use the Jetty dependency because I think I will have issues with the Dispatcher module on AEM. Any input here would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated Google pay pass and for this I used `GoogleCredential` class.

First get the service account which has private key in it
And the use the below code

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential.fromStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/sericeaccountinfo.json"), 
  restMethods.getHttpTransport(), 
                 jsonFactory)
                .createScoped(config.getScopes());
```

More details : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

Comment: Thanks @Pakira, i'm trying with that approach. I'll let you know if i can save data on the google sheets.

Comment: i've managed to make it work with google-api-services-sheets v4-rev515-1.23.0